# Smooth scrolling in a QListView (or QAbstractItemView)

Tags: scroll, smoothing, qlistview

I have a QListView that displays square-shaped items. My problem is that when I scroll this list, it scrolls one entire row of squares at a time, and I think that doesn't look right. Instead, I would like the list to scroll 1 pixels or two at a time - i.e. smoothly. It's mostly a cosmetic change. Any idea how I would do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok I just found there's a property for that:

```
listView->setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel);
```

The other option, the default, is ScrollPerItem.

Answer (score 3):

Tried your solution and it didn't work for me.
But it worked well when i added:

```
listView -> verticalScrollBar() -> setSingleStep(5);
```

Or something like that, sorry for mistakes if there are any, i'm writing in PyQt5:

```
listView.verticalScrollBar().setSingleStep(5)
```

Edit: oh, i haven't noticed the year of this answer...

Comment: Thanks for your late answer, scroll per pixel didn't work for me. I had to set the single steps as you did!